# Cannot reach my .NET container

Tags: .net, docker, centos, docker-compose

I'm using a virtual machine which has CentOS 7.4.1708 with Docker and docker-compose installed to deploy a .NET application with an MSSQL server.
However, despite the fact that docker-compose can both build and run the image and container I cannot reach it from my host or the dockerhost.
I've tried using a Firefox, Google, wget and Invoke-Webrequest from my host and the dockerhost tolocalhost:8080, 0.0.0.0:8080, ipaddressvm:8080 and ipaddresscontainer:8080.

I think it might be a problem with the ports or the Docker image that I'm using.
However, I've added all the necessary ports to the firewall and that didn't appear to fix the problem.
The Docker image that I'm using seems to work fine. It's microsoft/dotnet:2.0.5-sdk-2.1.4, the same as my .NET project.

I've included my dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and firewall-rules below:

```
cat > Dockerfile << EOF 
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.5-sdk-2.1.4

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet build

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
EOF

cat > docker-compose.yml << EOF 
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Vagrant123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
EOF

firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-port=1433/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I'm a bit at my wits end.
I've already tried adding a static route to it, using the default port of 80, adding http- and https service to the firewall and troubleshoot using the TCP/IP stack as far as it's possible for containers.
I can't rightly tell where I went wrong, nor can I troubleshoot it any further.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check password requirements

Your password (such as `Vagrant123`) doesn't meet the [complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017). So try adding a non-alphanumeric characters such as exclamation point (`!`).

#### Check logs

To check for errors, run: `docker logs ID` (where `ID` is your SQL container ID from `docker ps`).